# formatting cells in excel using python

Tags: python, excel, parsing, merge, center

Hi I'm using python to parse through an excel file and copy only the contents I want to another excel file however, I want the new cells formatted in a different way.  Currently I'm using the xlrd and xlwt libraries.  I looked at the documentation on their website and it doesn't seem to address it, only font formatting such as bolding and underlining.  Specifically I want my new copied cells centered and some of the other cells merged. Any ideas?

Comment: check out this link: http://www.youlikeprogramming.com/2011/04/examples-generating-excel-documents-using-pythons-xlwt/

Comment: Take a look at openpyxl if xlsx format files are ok for your use.  I have found it to be much more friendly than xlrd/xlwt.  http://pythonhosted.org/openpyxl/ and http://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update:
I have found the solution by importing easyxf from xlwt

I set the styles by the statement:

style = easyxf('align:horizontal center;')

so when i write to the sheet i can use:

sheet.write(row, col, item_to_write, style)

Documentation from:
http://www.simplistix.co.uk/presentations/python-excel.pdf

Answer (score 1):

In the comments, Joe points out that formatting is supported by xlrd and xlwt. However, you also can use win32com to drive excel directly.

See: [Using Automation Objects from Python](http://oreilly.com/catalog/pythonwin32/chapter/ch12.html#49339)

Once you have this working you can do pretty much anything excel can do. 
Unfortunately there isn't complete documentation. The best bet is to read the excel VB documentation (for the version you have) and guess at the python binding.

If you know the general format, it's easiest to start with an excel file that has all the formatting and formulas predefined.

Comment: Oh, good. I'll edit the answer. Do they support formulas and charting as well? If so I may migrate. It would be way better than fighting win32com/excel versions/etc.

Comment: [XlsxWriter](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org) supports [charts](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/chart_examples.html).

Comment: @joshua: Is there a method in win32com that allows me to set the orientation of an Excel sheet to landscape?

Comment: I haven't tried it, but if you can do it in a macro then you can do it with win32com. Record a macro then look at the generated VB source. Use that as a basis to guess the python.